# What are "structures" in mathematical proof?

Tags: proof-writing, definition

In my class textbook, it defines a theory as

> a collection of true statements called theorems that describe patterns or relationships among quantities and structures.

I looked at the previous section and even online to get more insight on what is meant by "structures", but I haven't found anything. Would examples of a "structure" in mathematical proof be functions, relations, etc?

Comment: How is your question related to [tag:proof-writing]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Because I'm looking for a definition that is related to proof-writing.

Comment: I understand structures in this context to mean things like sets, functions, algebraic structures (e.g. groups, rings, fields), collections of sets, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structures are concepts such as groups, vector spaces, manifolds, and so on. Consider for instance the statement “On a finite-dimensional real vector space, all metrics are equivalent”. In the context of real vector spaces it relates the condition that such a space if finite-dimensional with something concerning the norms that we can define on it.